# jQuery, adding new element when table is loaded

Tags: jquery, css

I have below code and I'd like to have this class name when the table is loaded. 
I tried `$('#currentNewSettingTable').ready`, but it was not working. What would be the proper solution to this?
This function is currently under :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#currentNewSettingTable').hover(
            function() {
                $(this).find('tr').each( function() {
                    if (!isMatching($(this))) $(this).addClass('newSettingHighlight');               
                });
            }, function() {          
                $(this).find('tr').removeClass('newSettingHighlight'); 
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what your want to achieve. Do you want the whole table to change on hover or juste each row at a time?

Comment: i need to highlight the row when the page is loaded. not just only on hover

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I propose the following scenario:

1. After the page is loading, we highlight the table for some time (lets say 3 seconds), after what it returns to it default state (not highlighted)
2. Then we add an effect to highlight each row when hovered.

The highlight and hover effects can easilly be done using CSS rules, we just use JavaScript to apply the correct CSS class to activate/deactivate effects.

**Note :** The highlight effect can be animated (and way nicer) though [CSS transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) but to keep it simple, I just add an ugly red border.

So, I've devided the differents states of the table in several CSS classes :

```
/* DEFAULT STATE */
#my-table {
  width: 100%;
}

#my-table tbody tr {
  background: #e2e2e2;
}

#my-table td {
  padding: 2px;
}

/* HILIGHTED STATE */
.highlighted-table {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

/* ROW HOVER EFFECT */
#my-table.hover-effect-table tbody tr:hover {
  background: pink;
}
```

And use a little bit of javaScript (jQuery) to add/remove this classes when I needed.
To add some delay, I use JavaScript [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function.

**Note:** To decompose the actions I separate them in 2 functions:

After page is loaded, when trigger highligthTable (after 1s).

HighlightTable wait for 3s, then remove the highlight effet and add the hover one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // After page is loaded, we wait 1s, then add highlight class to the table
    setTimeout(function(){
        highlightTable();
    }, 1000);
});


function highlightTable() {
    $('#my-table').addClass('highlighted-table');

    //The table will be higlithed for 3 seconds, 
    // then it returns to it's default state
    // and we add class that allow hover effect on it's rows
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#my-table').removeClass('highlighted-table')
                            .addClass('hover-effect-table');
    }, 3000);
}
```

Here is the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/kmmxgr8v/